# Four finger gesture in Fusuma/xdotool to change tab in Chrome?

Tags: 20.04, touchpad, multi-touch, xdotool, libinput

I'm trying to use Fusuma/Xdotool to do a 4 finger swipe left/right to change tab in Chrome (i.e. to trigger alt+tab and alt+shift+tab. However, it doesn't seem to work. Other 3 and 4 finger gestures are recognized. Running Ubuntu 20.04.

This is my config:

```
swipe:
  3: 
    left: 
      command: 'xdotool key alt+Left'
    right: 
      command: 'xdotool key alt+Right'
    up: 
      command: 'xdotool key ctrl+t'
    down: 
      command: 'xdotool key ctrl+w'
  4:
    left: 
      command: 'xdotool key ctrl+Tab'
    right: 
      command: 'xdotool key ctrl+alt+Tab'
    up: 
      command: 'xdotool key super'
    down: 
      command: 'xdotool key super'
pinch:
  in:
    command: 'xdotool keydown ctrl click 4 keyup ctrl'
  out:
    command: 'xdotool keydown ctrl click 5 keyup ctrl'
```

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

`xdotool key ctrl+Page_Up` # Switch to prev tab

`xdotool key ctrl+Page_Down` # Switch to next tab

This works for me

Comment: This answer is not reproducible because there is no formatting to distinguish the commands from the surrounding text.  Please use the editing tools at the top of the text box when [editing](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1295246/edit) your post.  If you are suggesting to enter commands in a terminal, please render these commands in a `monospace` font.  Alternatively, you can use [Markdown](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting) to format your posts.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome uses Ctrl+Tab to switch tabs to the right and Ctrl+Shift+Tab to go to the left.

```
4:
    right: 
      command: 'xdotool key ctrl+Tab'
    left: 
      command: 'xdotool key ctrl+Shift+Tab'
```